# Spell checking in Shell

Tags: tools, spelling

I know I can use `TeXShop` or any other word processing program to spell check my document, but I was wondering, if there are any spell checking scripts, which run in a shell/Terminal.

I saw that there is a program called `aspell`, but it hasn't been updated for a long time. Are there any good programs/scrips out there?

Answer (score 2):

## aspell

Although `aspell` has been mentioned, I would like to give some usage examples.

### Basic usage

```
aspell --mode=tex -c sample-file.tex
```

### Languages

List all dictionaries:

```
aspell dump dicts
```

Change language to check:

```
aspell --lang=de --mode=tex -c sample-file.tex
```

### Downsides of aspell

The following is from a German document I've just written. It has 413 lines, so it is rather small.

This should have been recognized as LaTeX, but wasn't:

Before `\begin{document}`:

- `\sisetup{locale=DE}` - "locale"
- `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{strrepeat}{2}{%` - "strrepeat"

  - `pgfmathint{#2}\pgfmath@count\pgfmathresult` and twice later - 3x"count"
  - `\let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty` - "empty"
  - `\pgfutil@loop` - "loop"
  - `\pgfutil@repeat` - "repeat"
- `\pgfmath@smuggleone` - "smuggleone"
- `\algtext*{EndIf}` - "EndIf", "EndWhile", "EndFunction"
- `\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, shapes}` - "arrows", "positioning", "calc", "shapes"
- `\DeclareMathOperator{\ggT}{ggT}` - "ggT" (That is valid in a German document about math)

25x words in:

```
\tikzset{
  Stern Brocot at/.style={at/.pgfmath={
      strcat("([rotate around=180:(!", strrepeat("#1",\SBLevel),")] !",
                                       strrepeat("#1",\SBLevel-1),"2)")}},
  Stern Brocot at*/.style n args={3}{
    at/.pgfmath={strcat("(!",strrepeat("#1",#2),"-| SB@#3)")},
    append after command/.expanded={\ifnum#2<\SBLevel(\noexpand\tikzlastnode)
      edge[densely dotted] (SB@#3@\the\numexpr\SBLLoop+1\relax)\fi}}}
```

After `\begin{document}`:

- Almost everything within TikZ
- Much in `algorithm` environment
- `\begin{tabular}{l||ccl}` - "ccl"

aspell also has problems with hyphenated words ([source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.aspell.user/1323))

### Workarounds

Create a file called `my_def.tex` and put your whole preamble in it.
Then add `\include{my_def}` to your preamble. It should be your file in there.

However, this does not solve the TikZ / table issue. But you can apply the same workaround for TikZ images. I guess it is not convenient to do so for tables.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `aspell` has not been updated for a long time IMHO means that it is good. I use it regularly. You only face a problem of recognizing LaTeX keywords, but after couple documents, you add most of them into your dictionary and then you happily spell-check ;)

Comment: how do you add them to your dictionary permanently?

Comment: There's a shortcut for that: `l` if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

While `aspell` still works well, the new rage seems to be [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/). It can also check LaTeX files.

Comment: Do you know how to install dictionaries for `hunspell`? Can' seem to figure it out. Running `hunspell -d en_US $FILENAME` gives me the error: `Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "en_US"`

Comment: @cherrung My dictionaries came with packages like `myspell-american` etc., since `hunspell` is based on `myspell`. I don't know how those packages are called on the Mac (you are on a Mac, right?).